# Program is unable to handle Errors

Tags: python, error-handling, port, host, port-scanning

1. Here's the source code for a Fast Host Port Scanner... I added some error handling... but the program is unable to read that error handling thing and it just gives out the normal python error when the host is invalid... Where am I getting it wrong?
2. How do I print the output of this program to a Text File? (I have tried it at the end but it doesnt work.

Would be Thankful to any help!!

SOURCE CODE:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import socket
import concurrent.futures
import subprocess
import sys
from datetime import datetime
    
# Clear the screen
subprocess.call('clear', shell=True)

# Ask for input
remoteServer = input("Enter a remote host to scan: ")
remoteServerIP  = socket.gethostbyname(remoteServer)

# Prints a banner with info on which host we are about to scan
print ("-" * 60)
print ("Please wait, scanning remote host", remoteServerIP)
print ("-" * 60)

# Check what time the scan started
t1 = datetime.now()

def scan(remoteServerIP, port):
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.settimeout(1)
    
    try:
        remoteServerIP  = socket.gethostbyname(remoteServer)
        result = sock.connect_ex((remoteServerIP, port))        
        if result == 0:
            print ("Port {}:      Open".format(port))
            sock.close()
            
    # We have also put in error handling for catching errors
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print ("You pressed Ctrl+C")
        sys.exit()

    except socket.gaierror:
        print ('Hostname could not be resolved. Exiting')
        sys.exit()

    except socket.error:
        print ("Host is not available",)
        sys.exit()

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=75) as executor:
    for port in range(1,1025):
        executor.submit(scan, remoteServerIP, port + 1)

# Checking the time again
t2 = datetime.now()

# Calculates the difference of time, to see how long it took to run the script
total =  t2 - t1

# Printing the information to screen
print ('Scanning Completed in: ', total)

#Text file
f = open('Hostreport.txt', 'a')
print(port,file=f)
f.close()
```

Current OUTPUT Im getting (When etering invalid host):

[OUTPUT SS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKPmo.png)

Comment: The ip address never used underscore.

Comment: @toyotaSupra i know thats why I added that so that It will generate a error and I could test the error handler...

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/

Answer (score 0):

You are not handling the error! Your error happens on this line. not inside the try except block

```
# Ask for input
remoteServer = input("Enter a remote host to scan: ")
remoteServerIP  = socket.gethostbyname(remoteServer)  # this one.
```

Comment: Ok I have removed this line from beginning and now its printing the print statement in except block 2 i.e gaierror in loop of 1025  ... how do I fix that

Comment: good. now you have caught the error. Which is what you wanted to do. Fixing the error is a completely new question.  If your current problem is solved. mark the answer as accepted. And if you are still facing some other issue. Create a new question with details of the issue. I see that you are new here. Welcome to stackoverflow. [some useful stuff about using this site](https://stackoverflow.com/help)